# opening an AVI video in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv, codec, avi

I have an AVI video and i want to change its codec to CVID due to 
an error happening in visual studio where only video with this codec can be opened

we are using opencv 2.1 to open the avi video and 
we used the video provided by the opencv file and it worked and its codec is CVID

we used a lot of types of converters but non of their results have worked 
we also tried to covert the avi video to a different format and then converted back to avi 
but also it did not work

so can you help us please ?

Answer (score 0):

Converting video is quite a complex process. Unless you can find some ready-made code, you'll have to interpret each frame of the AVI. This means, read the headerformat of the AVI itself, then read the first N frames, and feed the frames into a store that uses your CVID encoder.

This sounds really simple, but the video is usually stored in a complex compressed form, and you will need to decompress it into a suitable form for the CVID encoder.

Typically, video frames consist of "Key frames" (pretty much every pixel is in the frame) and "delta frames", which contain "update sections" for the key frame), so you will need to understand which type of frame it is.

Obviously, converting it back to AVI is the same process in reverse.

I don't know the internal format of AVI, or how different CVID is. But I'm pretty sure the easiest way is to find some existing software that does this.